# Downgrade Linux Kernel Version

Tags: linux-kernel, version, downgrade

I want to downgrade my kernel version on Ubuntu 16.04.3.

However, when I do 'dpkg -l | grep linux-image', the output is like this:

[image]

and when I do 'uname -r', the output is like this:

[image]

The problem is that I want to remove 4.15.0.24-generic and downgrade it to 4.13, but cannot find 4.15.0.24 on linux-image list.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to display your Grub is to press and hold the SHIFT button while booting. Then select Advanced option for Ubuntu and choose your kernel version

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried pressing SHIFT while booting, but there is no difference. Just boot normally. Are there any things that I have to do? I use Ubuntu LTS 16.04.3.

Comment: @SON.PARK in some case its can be right shift instead left but I'm using same ubuntu its works for me with left shift.